# Recovering data lost in Google Apps transition

Tags: google-workspace, rss, export

I use Google Apps for my domain. Until recently, I was required to sustain a Google Account separate from my Google Apps Account for products like Reader or Analytics. This changed when Google began a consolidation of such split accounts, ostensibly merging Account data into Apps Account Data. I have so called "conflicting" Accounts owing to my use of the same email address for both Accounts.

On forced transition day, however, I lost the data associated with my Reader and Analytics account. Both are now empty. Google's help forums have not been helpful. Moreover, the support documentation asserts that I should have:

- been presented with a conflict resolution page, allowing me to change the account name on the non-Apps Account
- been able to successfully consolidate data into the Apps Account.

Neither proved true. I am unable to login to my old Account and cannot rescue the Reader data meticulously collected over several years. Presumably Google still *holds* the data I so desire to export, but I cannot attract the attention of staff so that I might get *my* data.

What are my options?

Comment: At this time is not possible to have two Google accounts with the same email address. By the other hand there were a lot of changes since 2011, one of the most relevants is that now all the Google user credentials were unified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a long shot, but try Twitter. I was able to get the attention of the right authorities which lead to a speedy resolution—they were different companies.

Comment: I have never used Twitter, I'm afraid. Who would I spew twits to?

Comment: Well, anyway, thanks for your suggestion, Sameer. This question was shifted to Webapps--a graveyard in the StackExchange network if ever there was one.